# Database Trigger - Max items in table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

So I am creating a database for a website.  Within this database, there is a table called 'featured'.  I need to make sure that there is at most 25 items in this table at any given time.  In order to accomplish this goal, I created a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER featured_check AFTER INSERT ON featured
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM featured) > 25 THEN
                DELETE FROM featured ORDER BY featured_id LIMIT 1;
            END IF;
        END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This trigger should be activated each time an item is inserted into the featured table.  It will count the number of items in the table, and if the count is over 25, it will delete the item with the lowest id.  'featured_id' in this case is an auto incrementing primary key.

Given all of this information, I have two questions:

1. Does this trigger do what I think it is doing?  I am no expert on databases and I just wanted to make sure.
2. Is this the best way to go about this issue?  Is there a better way to prevent the table from having more than 25 items?

Comment: 1. I would create a table with 25 rows and a trigger, and simply check for myself.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could create a table with a set number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could simplify the trigger code sql by removing the if and using

```
DELETE FROM featured
WHERE featured_id IN
      (SELECT MIN(featured_id)
       FROM   featured
       HAVING COUNT(*)>24)
```

but otherwise looks ok to me.